# NodeJS & Passport.js - Cookie expiring before set time

Tags: node.js, cookies, redis, passport.js, session-cookies

I have implemented AUTH with Passport.js using Redis as session storage. Everything works well but for some reason, the cookie expires much earlier than the set time (if the website is not open/active on the browser after some hours). I'm not very familiar with cookies & passport.js overall. Could any of these configurations invalidate the session cookie before the maxAge field. Thank you in advance!

```
sessionMiddleware: session({
        secret: 'MY_SECRET',
        resave: false,
        proxy: true,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
        cookie: {
            domain: 'example.com',
            secure: true, // true for production (https)
            sameSite: 'None',
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4,
            httpOnly: true,
            path: '/',
        },
    }),
```